# Pregunta puesta en espera, justificación

Tags: discusión

Me encontré con [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32137/como-borrar-una-gr%C3%A1fica-para-poner-otra) sobre [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) y [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) que fue puesta en espera por varios usuarios con el motivo de:

```
puesto en espera como no está claro lo que se pregunta
```

Son dos dudas que bajo mi punto de vista son concretas y fáciles de entender para cualquiera que use estas librerías:

- Actualizar una gráfica en [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/)
- Guardar datos generados por una función en un txt (en concreto desde una lista) usando un botón de [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html)

Entendería que sin el código la pregunta sería demasiado ambigua pero el código se incluía desde el principio (viendo el historial de [ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/32137/revisions)). Personalmente no veo motivos para ponerla en espera o para cerrarla, ¿o se me escapa algo?

Por otro lado, el código lo pone en un link a Mega, personalmente me gusta que el código esté en el cuerpo de la pregunta incluido directamente (con su correcto formato) ya que no depende de enlaces externos que pueden caer en un futuro y es más fácil para los demás usuarios ya que el acceso es directo y no hay que andar haciendo clic a paginas externas. Por esta razón, la edite incluyendo el código del enlace en la pregunta directamente pero fue rechazada la edición (2 votos contra 1).

Es cierto que el código es algo largo, pero no demasiado (unas 100 líneas). Mi pregunta es si en estos casos es correcto editar para añadir el código del enlace externo (y posiblemente perecedero en el futuro) al propio cuerpo de la pregunta con su formato apropiado o si es mejor dejar el link. Por otro lado, ¿si el código es algo largo (como las 100 líneas de este) es preferible el link externo?

Como reflexión personal, la pregunta además tenía 3 votos negativos y no se hace ni un solo comentario para decirle al usuario que está haciendo mal. Creo que se debería ser más dialogante con usuarios 'nuevos' como en este caso para no ahuyentarlos a la primera cerrándoles preguntas y cosiéndolos a negativos para facilitar que crezca la comunidad.

Comment: Acabo de reabrirla. Gracias por el aviso.

Comment: Gracias @Luiggi Mendoza por reabrirla. Voy a contestarla ahora mismo.

Comment: Sí, la publicación original estaba bastante mal... Con esas ediciones que hicieron está mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Yo vengo observando bastante poca tolerancia a preguntas, llamémoslas, difusas. De hecho, algunas de ellas sí que concretan lo que se quiere preguntar y aun así, las cosen a votos de cierre. Sin ir más lejos, esta es otro caso: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32193/es-posible-utilizar-desde-un-action-las-clases-que-chequean-los-requisitos-de-in

A poco que conozcas symfony, aunque sea por encima, se sabe de qué se está hablando, sin embargo muchos de los que la han votado ni siquiera cuentan con symfony entre sus etiquetas principales.

Todos queremos que SO en español sea una fuente de conocimiento de calidad, pero vamos a ser tolerantes o espantaremos a los que más ayudan necesitan precisamente.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que es mejor ser modestos y reconocer que si no somos expertos en la materia, tal vez sea parte de la razon por la que no entendemos la pregunta. Interesantemente, he visto lo opuesto también, donde se reabren preguntas que "parecen" tener bastante detalles, pero que para un experto, es obvio que le falta la informacion basica necesaria para contestar la pregunta. En ambos casos, el problema es el mismo: falta de modestia.

Comment: Parte de mi labor cuando veo una pregunta ecerrada es ver quiénes son los usuarios que la cerraron y si ellos tienen puntaje favorable en esas etiquetas. No es un indicador al 100% de experiencia pero si veo que no tienen tan siquiera una respuesta publicada para la etiqueta principal (dígase el LP) entonces considero como si fuesen votos nulos y re evalúo la decisión de cierre. Esto **no significa** que, dadas estas circunstancias, vaya a re abrir la pregunta.

Comment: se me ocurrio una idea al leer tu respuesta. que si alguien quiera votar para cerrar una pregunta debe de tener al menos 5 preguntas/respuestas en la etiqueta en la cual se marco la pregunta.

Comment: @bassily, podría ser... pero no creo que sea necesario imponer una medida para resolver algo que el sentido común puede hacer por si mismo...

Comment: Es cierto lo que dices @sstan, hay preguntas que parecen bien hechas, con su código y todo, que no hay por donde cogerlas porque falta información esencial, pero para alguien que no domine esa librería en concreto puede parecer una buena pregunta. En estos casos es esencial el trabajo de los moderadores pero todos podemos ayudar a mejorar y la mejor forma es hablando a mi parecer. Creo que en estos casos lo mejor es avisar siempre al usuario con un comentario diciendo que esta mal y dar la oportunidad para que lo arregle, si no pues se cierra y no pasa nada.

Comment: La principal razón por la que comenté esto aquí (al margen de la pregunta en si) es que observo a menudo preguntas puestas en espera sin ni siquiera un comentario diciendo al usuario que está mal y que debe hacer para corregirlo. Soy partidario de ser inflexible con algunos casos como los ejercicios de tareas copiados y pegados (hay que tener cara) pero en muchos otros casos deberíamos ser flexibles y interactuar con el que hace la pregunta para que la mejore, sobre todo con usuarios 'novatos' para no ahuyentarlos y que esta comunidad crezca.

Comment: Habría que reflexionar que si cuando se vota por el cierre o puesta en espera no somos capaces de poner un comentario diciendo que es lo que está mál específicamente, tal vez deberiamos replantearnos ese voto. En general creo que esta comunidad está muy bien moderada y autogestionada, es mejorable y todos nos equivocamos (más cuando algunas cosas son subjetivas) pero tener una base de conocimientos de calidad en el 3º idiomas con mas hablantes del mundo (el 2º si solo contamos nativos) merece la pena  y cuanta más gente (seria) consigamos atraer mejor.